# Image File From Local Storage to ImageView - android 10 Storage Permissions Issue

Tags: android, android-imageview

Not sure where I am making an error, but I have tried everything to get an image to display in `ImageView` once the user selects an Image in Image Picker but **let's leave the image picker aside** I can't even show the image by directly providing the FullPath as in code below (not getting any error either)

**Try 1 - Bitmap**

```
string IMGpath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151102_193132.jpg"
var imgFile = new File(IMGpath);
if (imgFile.Exists())
 {       
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgFile.AbsolutePath);     
  _imageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }
else
  {
    Log.Info("AAABL", "No file");
  }
```

**Try 2 - Bitmap with options**

```
string IMGpath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151102_193132.jpg"
    var imgFile = new File(IMGpath);
    if (imgFile.Exists())
     { 
      BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imgFile.AbsolutePath, bmOptions);
      bitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200,200, true);
      _imageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
    else
      {
        Log.Info("AAABL", "No file");
      }
```

**Try 3 - Custom Library**
In addition, I tried to use [a Library](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Android-API)  as follows

```
string IMGpath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151102_193132.jpg"
        var imgFile = new File(IMGpath);
        if (imgFile.Exists())
         { 
           var a = ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(imgFile.AbsolutePath)
                            .Retry(3, 200)
                            .Into(_imageview);
          }
        else
          {
            Log.Info("AAABL", "No file");
          }
```

**Try 4 - URI**

```
string IMGpath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151102_193132.jpg"
Android.Net.Uri URI = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(IMGpath );
_imageview.SetImageURI(URI );
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the image to load. I have the following **permissions in manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And also checking Permissions on Activity `OnCreate` Method to ensure the app has full permissions to storage as following

```
if ((ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted) && (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted))
   {
     ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
   }
```

**This only happens in Android 10 (API 29) where same code works fine up to API 28.**

This is one heck of a soul crusher, whole day and I couldn't figure it out, any idea?

**UPDATE**::
When tried to open the file I get the following error

> **open failed:** EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: What is the API level you are using? 23+?

Comment: Are you sure the image view is displayed? Maybe visibility is invisible or gone. Try using glide or picasso to display a image on internet.

Comment: Also add File.canRead(). Is this Android Q? How did you obtain that path? The 'filepicker' will never give you such a path! You used someting like get real path from uri. Dont do such things.

Comment: hi @blackapps I think you are onto something, I can't read the file I get the error `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue and found your post, then afterwards found a potential solution for you here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3896#issuecomment-533062076

Just add this to your manifest's application tag. It fixed the issue for me on 10:

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: This will work, but it's not a good answer. Not sure how long this will work.

Comment: Works but not a permanent solution,  Manually granting storage permissions in the app settings and it works. For some reason, androidQ doesn't grant storage permissions when a user clicks on 'Grant'

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the file (or file path) to a `ContentProvider` URI:

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.myapp.app.fileprovider", imgFile);
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentUri);
```

Use the provider as defined in the `<provider>` section if the manifest.

A more "manual" method would be something like this (example for an image in the MediaStore):

```
Uri uri = null;
Uri photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri("external");
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri, projection, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        long photoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
        uri = Uri.parse(photoUri.toString() + "/" + photoId);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Comment: I will try it out, it seems like a Storage permissions issue on androidQ, Manually granting storage permissions in the app settings and it works. For some reason, androidQ doesn't grant storage permissions when a user clicks on 'Grant' - any ideas why